# Magento final price from web service

Tags: web-services, magento

because of MAGE price calculation complexity + EPR incompatibility with MAGE calculation, I was thinking about overriding getPrice() and getFinalPrice() methods in a way, that they will call external webservice for a requested price.
Does anybody tried to solve price calculation in a suggested way and if, does this work in a real environment?

Second option is to reverse engineer price engine from ERP in MAGE database (additinal tables + logic inside MAGE).

What do you tink? Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work and testing, I did new models in Magento and reimplement price calculation logic based od ERP rules. Webservice would work, but it would be very very slow(call to getPrice or getFinalPrice is executed at least twice for every item displayed).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with complex pricing issues.
I ended up with adding some custom attribute fields that where dynamically chosen on the 
customer number.

Could you give me some background on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

we have very complex price calculation. Every customer has its own pricing rules(per product,per product group, special discount, etc..). 
There is 15.000 customers and 60.000 items.

It is possible to add all rules into MAGE, but price indexing takes very, very long and MAGE is almost unusable. pricing engine on the other hand is not so hard to implement, but a question remain if it is possible to use price engine from ERP(ERP has API for getting a price) or is it better to implement it inside MAGE (on mysql) with extending original logic.
There is no need to have administrator GUI for checking prices, because sync is done automatically and never entered by the user. (A goal is to completely replace pricing logic from MAGE).
Thank for your answer.